# Datagrid validation on cells, extending properties of entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, datagrid

I use entity framework to get my result from the database. This is used to set the source of a datagrid. I need to perform validation on the data grid while editing and adding new rows.  I need to add required field validator for some of the columns in the datagrid.
Also I need to set the default property, can the constructor of the class be extended?

I set the datasource for the datagrid as follows:

```
<DataGrid Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding TestList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5,5,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinRowHeight="30" CanUserAddRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="132">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Name" ToolTip="Enter the name of a test
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>                    
        </DataGridTextColumn>                
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```